# New Winterbash menu doesn't open on hover

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar, winter-bash

If you click on the Stack Exchange menu or the inbox menu or the achievements/reputation menu, you can then move the mouse between those three menus without any additional clicks.

This behaviour does not appear to be applying to the Winterbash menu (or the "help" menu for that matter, but that's on the other side of the bar).

Could we get this sorted, since otherwise the behaviour is a little inconsistent, with extra clicking on a menu bar where in all other circumstances clicking would close the menu!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did it this way one purpose. Winter Bash is still a fun thing after all, while the inbox/achievements popups are important to using the site. Winter Bash isn't on the same level of importance, and it shouldn't get in your way when using the site otherwise. If you actually want to look at your Winter Bash inbox, you actually have to click it.

Comment: Winterbash **isn't on the same level of importance**? What is the world coming to? Aren't **HATS** more important than rep?

Comment: @hichris123 this so much!

Comment: As balpha said: "Winter Bash isn't on the same level of importance" - it's more important.