# Winter-Bash dropdown behavior inconsistent with other dropdowns in the top bar

Tags: bug, status-declined, top-bar, winter-bash-2013

The new winterbash dropdown and the help dropdown in the top bar behaves different from the other dropdowns:

- If an other dropdown is open I can hover over other normal dropdown triggers to open that instead. This does not work for the winterbash dropdown. E.g. if I press on the inbox dropdown and hover over the reputation dropdown, the reputation dropdown opens.
- Simmilary, if the winterbash dropdown is open hovering over the other dropdown items doesn't have any effect.
- Closing the winterbash dropdown with a click on the snow star adds a hash (`#`) at the end of the current URL.
- When the help dropdown is open and I hover over the inbox (or other dropdown menus) the other menu will not open.
- When an other dropdown than the help menu is open and I hove over the help dropdown the help dropdown does not open.

Comment: The help dropdown issue is mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211560/drop-down-menus-in-new-top-bar-react-inconsistently-to-click-hover-events?rq=1)

Comment: Close the other as dupe of this more complete bug report. :P

Comment: Exact duplicate of [New Winterbash menu doesn't open on hover](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211697/229699) - which has an answer

Comment: @Flyk you did not mention the help button or the hash when closing with the winter bash menu button. (which are 3 of 5 bullet points, so I don't see the "exact" point here.)

Comment: `(or the "help" menu for that matter, but that's on the other side of the bar).` - Since balpha has already mentioned he's not really all that fussed about minor breakages due to the length this event lasts, I doubt the # is going to warrant a fix either. So yeah - that's everything covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [balpha's answer on the question I asked earlier about the same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211701/229699):

> I did it this way one purpose. Winter Bash is still a fun thing after all, while the inbox/achievements popups are important to using the site. Winter Bash isn't on the same level of importance, and it shouldn't get in your way when using the site otherwise. If you actually want to look at your Winter Bash inbox, you actually have to click it.