# Winter Bash dropdown doesn't appear on sites I haven't joined

Tags: feature-request, bug, top-bar, winter-bash

When I go to a site I haven't joined, I can see my personal Stack Exchange SiteSwitcher™, inbox, and reputation dropdown. However, I can't see my (or any, for that matter) Winter Bash dropdown:

[image]

Could it be put there?

Comment: On the other hand, it's not as if you can wear a hat in a community you have not joined.

Comment: I'm almost certain this is by-design. Why would this be beneficial?

Comment: @FatherChristmas The same reason it's beneficial to have my other dropdowns there.

Comment: [Not all dropdowns are created equal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211701/1438), so consistency isn't a very compelling argument.

Comment: @FatherChristmas Hmm, good point.